# Wpf viewbox resizing after users click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

I have one viewbox that is getting resized after windows get loaded. After being completed loaded the window is getting resized when I clicked somewhere in the window or resize it:

```
<Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5">
                    <Grid Background="White">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"  MinWidth="150" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"  MinWidth="150" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image x:Name="ImgTwitterUserPhoto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" MaxWidth="150" MaxHeight="150" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                            <Grid  Grid.Column="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="White">

                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="80*"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Label x:Name="LblTwitterUserName" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0"
                                           FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="20"/>
                                    <Label x:Name="LblTwitterUserHandle" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12"
                                           FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" Grid.Row="1"
                                           Foreground="#FF8B8888" Opacity="0.8"/>
                            </Grid>


                    </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
```

Comment: Faka you downvotter. This seems to be a microsoft's buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I found the strange behavior:

In the main window(parent control) we have this option: SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"

In the first user interaction the main window ensure that all your controls respect that property. And because of that the controls get resized in width and height. The problem is that the controls are getting resized after user interaction, probably because the inner controls aspect ratio to be kept or something to the viewbox respecting its container size.

The solution was to replace WidthAndHeight with Width only, since the resizing came from vertical dimension.